# Why DbContext Caches the Data Submitted to the Database?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

i'm using Blazor-server.
i'm create repository with entityframworkcore and sql.

UserRepository.cs :

```
public class UserRepository
{
    AppContext _db;
    public UserRepository(AppContext context)
    {
        _db = context;
    }

    public Task AddAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        try
        {
            await _db.User.AddAsync(user, cancellationToken);
            int result = await _db.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

startup.cs :

```
services.AddSingleton<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
services.AddDbContext<AppContext>(ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

users.razor :

```
@inject IUserRepository userRepository
```

and

```
await userRepository.addAsync(user1);
```

If the operation related to "user1" fails, We will edit and resubmit user1 (user2)

```
await userRepository.addAsync(user2);
```

If the operation related to "user1" fails,
Then for the "user2" operation the same "user1" (userRepository.AddAsync(user2)), The object "user1" is reloaded into the database again
And back to the same error again
Also a number is added to db.User .Local.Count each time

Also, sometimes when I fetch a data from a database, edit it and update it, it will show pre-update information if I fetch the same data again

Comment: `AddSingleton` ← That is **not** advisable when working with a web application. You need an *instance* per request, not a shared instance across requests. Also don't inject your repository into your razor templates! The controller should contain the business logic (or a service that the controller calls). In this case you should be used `AddScoped` instead of `AddSigleton`.

Comment: And a DbContext will/can *track* (not cache) entities until they are manually removed from tracking. That is standard behavior and in normal operations this is OK. If you have a situation where this does not work please post an [mcve] with what you are trying to accomplish and where it does not work.

Comment: Because EF is the slowest ORM ever...... So they found hacks to try to mitigate the problem.

Comment: I injected the service into the Razor page
And repository inside the service
Here is a summary
I also used AddScope instead of AddSingleton, but the results did not differ